# Change image source depending of its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title already tell's a little bit. I'm getting a list of documents with links and images like this:

```
<img class="Thumbnail" src="sourcetothepdfimage.png" id="/path/pdf.png"/>
```

The only two things that may differ are src and id. What I try to reach now is to replace the image src depending on its ID. The ID may be `/path/pdf.png` or `/path/word.png` or something completely different (which I don't know yet).

What would be the recommended way to achieve this? I have three different images for the replacement (one for PDF, one for word files and one generic for all other unknown file types).
I think document.getElementByID doesn't make that much sense because I only know two fix IDs. With this I can change the src for PDF and DOCX but not for any other, right?
So `document.getElementsByClassName` would be the targeted solution, but how can I iterate through all five or more listed elements with the class "Thumbnail"?

I'm barely new to the Dev world and like to learn it.

Comment: (If you have any control over the HTML input, then please use a proper `data-` attribute for this, instead of “abusing” the id attribute this way.)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple using jQuery.

```
// get all img's using class selector
// and use `attr()` method with callback which iterate internally
// within the callback return the id( within callback this refers to the current element DOM object)
$('.Thumbnail').attr('src',function(){
   return this.id
})
```

```html
<img class="Thumbnail" src="sourcetothepdfimage.png" id="/path/pdf.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (no jquery)

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.Thumbnail')].map(img=> img.src=img.id);

console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('img')]);
```

```html
<img class="Thumbnail" src="sourcetothepdfimage.png" id="/path/pdf.png"/>
<img class="Thumbnail" src="sourcetothesomimage.png" id="/path/pdf2.png"/>
<img class="Thumbnail" src="sourcetothedocimage.png" id="/path/doc.docx"/>
```